# Строка с одинарной кавычкой и urlencode

Tags: php, url, строки

Вот есть строка.

```
var_dump string(24) "'G' Men (1935)"
```

Ее нужно вложить в `URL`, мне подходит `urlencode`  и должно получиться так:

```
%27G%27+Men+%281935%29
```

Делаю, получаю:

```
$title = "'G' Men (1935)";
$title = urlencode($title);
var_dump string(40) "%26%23039%3BG%26%23039%3B+Men+%281935%29"
```

Если вернуть назад `urldecode`:

```
$title = "'G' Men (1935)";
$title = urlencode($title);
$title  = urldecode($title);
var_dump string(24) "'G' Men (1935)"
```

Если экранировать кавычки в `'G' Men (1935)` с помощью `addslashes()`

```
$title = "'G' Men (1935)";
$title = addslashes($title);
var_dump string(24) "'G' Men (1935)"
```

И если еще так:

```
$title = "'G' Men (1935)";
$title = html_entity_decode(urlencode($title))
var_dump string(40) "%26%23039%3BG%26%23039%3B+Men+%281935%29"
```

Что нужно сделать со строкой, чтобы получить ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строка в вашем вопросе

```
var_dump string(40) "%26%23039%3BG%26%23039%3B+Men+%281935%29"
```

говорит, что в действительности `$title` у вас содержит в себе не

```
'G' Men (1935)
```

а

```
&#039;G&#039; Men (281935)
```

где `&#039;` - html код одинарной кавычки.

Сначала следует преобразовать все HTML-сущности в соответствующие символы с помощью [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php), а потом уже URL-кодирование строки делать

```
$title = "&#039;G&#039; Men (281935)";
var_dump(urlencode(html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

Результат

```
string(24) "%27G%27+Men+%28281935%29"
```

Comment: Да, так и есть. Спасибо!